# why is kCLErrorNetwork not being called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my iOS application i have a mapview and i'm trying to use the

`(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

method to see if the user has enabled location services and also if there is an internet connection.

In my .m i'm doing this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{


    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@\n\n\n", error);


    switch ([error code]) {
        case kCLErrorNetwork:{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"please check your internet connection or that you are not in airplane mode" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;

        case kCLErrorDenied:{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"enable location services to see your current position." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;

        default:{

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unknown network error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
    }

}
```

If the user doesn't allow the application to use location services, he will correctly get the "kCLErrorDenied" pop up. On the other hand though, if the ethernet cable from my pc(i'm using iPhone simulator) is removed i don't get the kCLErrorNetwork error.

Could it be the fact that on the iPhone simulator, even if there is no internet connection, wifi is always enabled?
What else could it be?

Thanks

Comment: Could anybody help me here? Any answer will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I see similar behavior on the device, if I turn on Airplane Mode (and make sure Wi-Fi is turned off). My guess is that it is an SDK bug, so I'd suggest filing one with Apple! I plan on doing some more research and filing a bug if I can't figure it out.